# Identify if the transaction is done via HCE or NFC?

Tags: nfc, emv, contactless-smartcard, hce

How do we identify if the transaction is done via HCE or NFC? Can we add any additional EMV tag to recognise the transaction?

Comment: If you are been able to emulate an EMV card (which is quite difficult as some data = keys are not available to the public) via HCE the POS terminal (= the tag reader) should not been able to detect any differences between the "emulated" and "original EMV/NFC card", so the answer is "a detection is not possible". In my comment I'm talking about EMV/payment cards like a Visa. If you should talk about transactions on other card types like "Mifare DESFire EVx" you should provide the tag name and type as an answer depends on the the tag.

Comment: Maybe to add to Michael's response - it is a little difficult to understand from the question which things are under your control. If both terminal (reader) and emulated card app then you have quite a selection of options. If only the HCE side then you will have more trouble but it may be doable. Out of the box they were meant to be transferring the same things. Please add more detail.